How to convert MEMS digital microphone to USB?
I have a camera + microphone combo PCB board removed from an all-in-one computer and I'm trying to reuse it. The camera is a standard USB device. The wires are even properly color coded. So I just needed to solder a USB plug to make it work. But I'm having some difficulty with the microphones (there's one for left and one for right).
The lettering on the chips is "AKU2004". Some quick Google searching indicates that they are digital MEMS Microphones. There are 5 wires. One of them is obviously GND. There isn't a Vcc. But since they share the PCB with the camera which has a USB port, it must be drawing power from it. If I don't plug in the camera, sure enough, the microphones don't work.
Of the remaining 4 wires, it appears that 2 are clock and 2 are data. I probed them with an oscilloscope, two of them carry ~2MHz square waves, with an amplitude of ~3.3v. So they must be clock wires. I know the data is PDM encoded. And the waveform looks like it is indeed PDM.
Now the question is, how do I interface them with a computer? Is there a chip that converts them to USB format? I also have a USB sound card that takes analog input, if it comes to that.
Thanks.

Is there a chip that converts them to USB format? the camera!

@JasenСлаваУкраїні No, why would it? Seriously, the USB camera module and the PDM mics just are on same PCB. The PDM mics connect to laptop sound chipset. Which is why your laptop also sees a sound device on PCI bus with speaker output and mic input and the camera via USB.

Right. The camera and the mics are separate devices. They happen to be on the same PCB.

If I don't plug in the camera, sure enough, the microphones don't work.  The microphone data sheet also shows their data lines connected to a camera module.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні The PDM mics on OP's board are powered from USB supply, so obviously they don't work if the USB is left unplugged. There is no reason why in a PC the mics were connected to a camera module, you can use the mics in any way you want, the camera may not even support mics.

Right, the mics just piggy-back on the camera's power. Otherwise they are not connected. The mics' data and clock wires are connected to the motherboard's audio codec, not as a USB device. If you're looking at method 2 in https://www.akustica.com/Files/Admin/PDFs/AN40-1%201%20AKU2002CH%20Mic%20Module%20Design%20Guide.pdf, it's a reference implementation, not the actual implement in my case.

Updates:

The so called "voice-to-bits" solution is apparently just a marketing term. The output of the microphone is just PDM. After applying a low pass filter, I get the analog audio signal.

I came upon this project https://www.hackster.io/sandeep-mistry/create-a-usb-microphone-with-the-raspberry-pi-pico-cc9bd5 that basically does what I want, except I have 2 mics.

So I hacked some code together and achieved interfacing the microphones with an RP2040 microcontroller. The code is here: https://github.com/delingren/mems-mic if anyone is interested. Be aware that it's all hard coded and hacky and I have no interest in cleaning it up and making it a library though.



For the "is there a chip" part, most likely there is.
Some USB sound interface chipsets may support PDM mics.
Some microcontrollers have USB interface which allows you to make an USB sound interface. Some microcontrollers also support PDM mics by having internal PDM to PCM converters.

Hmm, lemme look into that. I have a bunch of microcontrollers laying around.

Regarding AKU2004 there is a press release from Akustica
Akustica, Inc., ... [2006] announced the first fully integrated audio/video Universal Serial Bus (USB2.0) camera module reference design using Akustica digital microphones and a
video interface controller from RICOH Co. Ltd., the Japanese electronics giant. The camera module reference design pairs an array of Akustica’s new AKU2004 digital microphones with Ricoh’s new R5U872 USB2.0 audio/video interface controller that features a 4-channel digital microphone interface.
I could not find any technical details on the interface to AKU2004, which they call "Voice-to-Bits solution". At least they are not using any known serial interface name (PDM, I2S) in their descriptions. Datasheets are also not known to Google.
So I afraid you are on your own with this nearly 20-years-old module.

Thanks! I saw that press release too and couldn't find anything else. I'll probe it a little bit with a microcontroller and see what I can find.

You could connect a 20 kHz R/C low pass filter to the PDM outputs and feed the analog "line in" input of your sound card with this, using decoupling capacitors.
I would not expect very high quality, but it is worth a trial.
